# How to access the SharePoint REST API secured by MFA?

Tags: authentication

I want to access the SharePoint REST API secured by MFA from Powershell, it is not working? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below two approach :

1.Prerequisist - install `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi`

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mysite.Sharepoint.com/sites/abc" -UseWebLogin
```

2.Pre-requisist - `OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll`

```
Add-Type -Path "$currentScriptDir\OfficeDevPnpCore\OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll"
$authenticationManager = New-Object OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager
$siteUrl = "https://mysite.Sharepoint.com/sites/abc"
$clientContext = $authenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteUrl);
```